# How to configure apache to forward https requests to a Strapi/node application running on port 1337?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, apache2, proxypass

I have a Strapi/node js application running on port 1337, and I can reach it with:

http://my-ip:1337

I also have a domain associated in the same server and a working ssl certificate in apache2, so that in the browser I can use https:

https://my-domain.com

Now, when I try to use https to reach port 1337 like this:

https://my-domain.com:1337

I get an "This site can’t provide a secure connection" error.

I tried to edit my my-domain.ssl.conf in apache 2 with the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.my-domain
        ServerAlias my-domain
        DocumentRoot /var/www/my-domain/public_html
        ErrorLog /var/www/my-domain/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/my-domain/log/requests.log combined

        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:1337/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1337/

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But unluckily when I introduce the ProxyPass directive the server stops working without any meaningful error.
Both mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http are loaded in the apache2 configuration..

What could be the problem here? Thanks to anyone who can help with it!!

Answer (score 0):

Strapi/node js application running on port 1337 to https

1st Changes

Edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
  ServerName yourdomian-name.com
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  SSLProxyEngine On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:1337/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1337/
  ProxyPreserveHost On


  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomian-name.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomian-name.com/privkey.pem
```

2nd Changes

Edit this /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomian-name.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomian-name.com/privkey.pem
    ServerName yourdomian-name.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:1337/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1337/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
```

then restart apache2

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Check https://yourdomian-name.com

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change in `yourdomain-le-ssl.conf` and enable modules if not.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName yourdomain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your/private-key.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/your/chain-file.pem

    #This is important
    <Location "/">
        ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:1337/"
        ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:1337/"
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/yourdomain-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/yourdomain-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

That's it. Now just restart Apache.

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`